# How to receive continuous images using UDP C#

Tags: c#, udp

I am trying to develop an video chat application via UDP C#. I have an picture box that shows the webcam of the user continuously and sending to a specific port. But I don't know how to receive the Image
I am using a byte to image / image to byte converter class (which normally works fine) but when I put this code in a timer sequence I get this error

> 'A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself'
> here is my code :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image bitmap = pictureBox1.Image;
            byte[] sndcam = imageToByteArray(bitmap);

            string Ip = "127.0.0.1";
            int port = 1111;

            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Ip), port);
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            client.SendTo(sndcam, ep);
        }
```

I've seen few questions like this on Stackoverflow but I cloudn't find a satisfying answer
Should I use RTP instead ? If so , How ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess error describes itself. What is the size of the package, what you try to send? You need to separate your `sndcam` into chunks, and send them. Your client has some buffer size, so you need to send corresponding amount of data.

Comment: It's a 30fps camera module.but I don't think it's possible to cut images into pieces and reunite them, or is it?

Comment: Images - are just array of bytes, you could do whatever you want with them. Just the principle is, that your `client` has some buffer, and you need to fit into that buffer with your data.

Comment: so as I understand if I lower the camera quality it will work.Thank you